# how to use page scroll to id plugin on page template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have homepage which is created by using multiple small template pages in wordpress. I have set menus on it . now i want to go on particular section/ template using menu. like if i press contact menu button then it should go smoothly downwards of homepage where the contact template has been called. I am using "Page scroll to id" plugin of wordpress but its not working. I have also seen that this plugin work when the page is created by dashoard page. Please help me , how can i navigate to my template page/section using this plugin. If any other plugin is there , please tell me about it . i will try to use that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create smooth scroll on link click follow the below steps :

**Step 1:** Add section ids in menu href including #section1 from admin section `Appearance >> Menu` .

**Step 2:** Create section or div with id name section1.

```
<div id="section1"></div>
```

**Step 3:** Paste the below code under your custom js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: it is working but why it take 1 - 2 seconds when i m click the menu?

Comment: Reduce the animation milliseconds parameters as according to your needs.